# convert string with nanosecond into timestamp in spark

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to convert a timestamp value with nano seconds to timestamp in spark. I get the input from a csv file and the timstamp value is of format 
`12-12-2015 14:09:36.992415+01:00`. This is the code I tried.

```
val date_raw_data = List((1, "12-12-2015 14:09:36.992415+01:00"))

val dateraw_df = sc.parallelize(date_raw_data).toDF("ID", "TIMESTAMP_VALUE")

val ts = unix_timestamp($"TIMESTAMP_VALUE", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffffz").cast("double").cast("timestamp")

val date_df = dateraw_df.withColumn("TIMESTAMP_CONV", ts).show(false)
```

The output is

```
+---+-----------------------+---------------------+
|ID |TIMESTAMP_VALUE        |TIMESTAMP_CONV       |
+---+-----------------------+---------------------+
|1  |12-12-2015 14:09:36.992|null                 |
+---+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

I was able to convert a time stamp with millisecond using format `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS`. Trouble is with nano second and timezone formats.

Comment: One correction the out put on TIMESTAMP_CONV   column is null which means conversion failed.

Comment: You can try provide Custom Schema to CSV with column value as Timestamp

Comment: I tried to use custom schema
`
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._;
val customSchema = StructType(
    Seq(StructField("ID", DataTypes.IntegerType, true), 
        StructField("TIMESTAMP_VALUE", DataTypes.TimestampType, true)
    )
);
`
But now I get error _java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer_

Comment: May be I should mention I am using spark 1.6

Comment: why not TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) ????

Answer (score 2):

`unix_timestamp` won't do here. Even if you could parse the string (AFAIK [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn't provide required formats), `unix_timestamp` [has only second precision](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@unix_timestamp(s:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,p:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (emphasis mine):

> `def unix_timestamp(s: Column, p: String): Column`
>
> Convert time string with given pattern (see [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html]) to Unix time stamp (**in seconds**), return null if fail.

You have to create your own function to parse this data. A rough idea:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def to_nano(c: Column) = {
  val r = "([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(\\.[0-9]*)(.*)$"
  // seconds part
  (unix_timestamp(
    concat(
      regexp_extract($"TIMESTAMP_VALUE", r, 1),
      regexp_extract($"TIMESTAMP_VALUE", r, 3)
    ), "MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ssXXX"
  ).cast("decimal(38, 9)") + 
  // subsecond part
  regexp_extract($"TIMESTAMP_VALUE", r, 2).cast("decimal(38, 9)")).alias("value")
}

Seq("12-12-2015 14:09:36.992415+01:00").toDF("TIMESTAMP_VALUE")
  .select(to_nano($"TIMESTAMP_COLUMN").cast("timestamp"))
  .show(false)

// +--------------------------+
// |value                     |
// +--------------------------+
// |2014-12-28 14:09:36.992415|
// +--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a dirty dirty trick without UDF to make this work if you don't care about nanoseconds. (I cannot use UDF where this is required, and cannot modify the source)

```
select CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(substr(date,0,length(date)-4), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") AS TIMESTAMP);
```

E.g.

```
select CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(substr("2020-09-14T01:14:15.596444Z",0,length("2020-09-14T01:14:15.596444Z")-4), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") AS TIMESTAMP);
```

I'm basically stripping the string out of it's nanoseconds part, and parsing the rest with the spark SimpleDateFormat compatible parser.

Please future employer, don't judge me by this reply.