# Timestamp casting makes value null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When cast the column datatype from string to timestamp the value becomes null.

I have values in the following format

```
20070811T00789.167861+0100
```

I want to cast the type to "timestamp", when i do the following

```
df.withColumn('arrivetime', df['arrivetime'].cast('timestamp'))
```

the value is becoming `null`. How to cast the column to timestamp without affecting the value and its format?

Comment: format of string is not readable..20071351 what date does it denotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert string with nanosecond into timestamp in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172432/convert-string-with-nanosecond-into-timestamp-in-spark)

Comment: Your edited sample data is still not valid. time part (....00789.167861+0100 ) of the timestamp should have HHmmss (6 digits), but u have only 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know exactly what format you are going for with the 5 digits for time and the 6 (nano seconds?) at the end, but do know that timestamps in Spark are milliseconds, not nanoseconds, so you are going to lose information.

That being said, you can use Spark's `unix_timestamp` method to convert strings to timestamps using the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) syntax.

First you probably have to get rid of the last 3 digits of the timestamp, by using Spark's `regexp_replace`

In Scala that would look like:

`regexp_replace(df("arrivetime"), """(\.\d{3})\d*""", """$1""")`

Then you could use the `unix_timestamp` like so:

`unix_timestamp([replaced string], "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSz")`