# Convert date string to timestamp for sorting on sub-second precision

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a column `date` in a pySpark dataframe with dates in the following format:

```python
2018-02-01T13:13:12.023507
```

I want to convert the dates in that column from string to timestamp (or something that I can sort it based on the date). So far I have tried the following:

```python
new_df = df.withColumn(
    'date', 
    unix_timestamp("date", "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.s").cast("double").cast("timestamp")
)
```

and this

```python
new_df = df.withColumn(
    'date',
    from_unixtime(
        unix_timestamp(col(('date')), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS"), 
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    )
)
```

and this

```python
df_new = df.withColumn(
    'date1',
    F.to_timestamp("date", "yyyy-dd-MM'T'hh:mm:ss.s")
)
```

I tried everything I found in other similar questions but so far nothing is working. I have also tried a different format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssss` with no success. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

for Spark >= 2.2 an alternative approach to `unix_timestamp()` is by using `to_timestamp()`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp

new_df = df.withColumn('converted_date',to_timestamp(col('date'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had the following DataFrame:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2018-02-01T13:13:12.023507', ), ('2018-02-01T13:13:12.323507', )], 
    ["date"]
)
df.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------+
#|date                      |
#+--------------------------+
#|2018-02-01T13:13:12.023507|
#|2018-02-01T13:13:12.323507|
#+--------------------------+
```

[`unixtimestamp` only supports second precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46173348/5858851). If you're only concerned with sorting based on the date, you can do the following:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp
df.withColumn(
    'new_date',
    unix_timestamp(col('date'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss").cast("timestamp")
).sort('new_date').show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------+---------------------+
#|date                      |new_date             |
#+--------------------------+---------------------+
#|2018-02-01T13:13:12.323507|2018-02-01 13:13:12.0|
#|2018-02-01T13:13:12.023507|2018-02-01 13:13:12.0|
#+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

But since these two example rows have the same date and time up to the second, the sorting here will be indeterminate.

If the sub-second portion is important to you, you can write your own function to handle that. One way is to split the `date` column on the `.` and divide by `1000000.0` to get the microseconds. Then add this to the `unixtimestamp` for sorting:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

df.withColumn(
    'order_column',
    unix_timestamp('date', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss") + split('date', "\.")[1]/1000000.0
).sort("order_column").show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------+-------------------+
#|date                      |order_column       |
#+--------------------------+-------------------+
#|2018-02-01T13:13:12.023507|1.517508792023507E9|
#|2018-02-01T13:13:12.323507|1.517508792323507E9|
#+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I think it should be `from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

You can  try udf like below.

> > > ```
> > >     format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%s'
> > >     func = udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, format), TimestampType())
> > > ```