# Convert various dateformats to a common date format in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

```
Spark SQL - 2.3 and 2.2. PySpark.
```

One date is `2019-11-19` and other is `2019-11-19T17:19:39.214841000000`.

Need to convert both to `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS`
Need to use in `spark.sql(select ......)`

So far have tried about 20 options but all are giving null.

Tried:

```
from_utc_timestamp(A.SE_TS, 'UTC')
    from_unixtime(A.SE_TS, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    from_unixtime(A.SE_TS)
to_date(A.SE_TS, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    to_date(A.SE_TS, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSS') (In many combinations of upper and lowercase)
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), "y-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ") - Gives syntax issues on ""
```

All are giving null.

Edit:
Data:

```
+--------------------------------+-------------+
|A.SE_TS                         |B.SE_TS      |
+--------------------------------+-------------+
|2019-11-19T17:19:39.214841000000|2019-11-19   |
+--------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Are there two variations in the same column is it?

Comment: Nope. Different columns

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of `df.select("date_col_1", "date_col_2").show()`? You're passing a `timestamp` level format to `to_date()`, whereas you want the output to be a `timestamp`. You should use `to_timestamp()`. `to_date()` truncates the hour, minute and second information

Comment: both are required to be in same dateformat of yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS . B.SE_TS could become 2019-11-19 00:00:00.000000 and A.SE_TS would become 2019-11-19 17:19:39.214841

Comment: Please also refer to this question which has no answer yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749233/pyspark-unable-to-change-the-format-of-timestamp-with-granularity-up-to-microse

Comment: Not a satisfactory response there. I have around 23 date columns. Spread across these two date formats. I cant implement that heavy operation in spark.sql("""select ......""")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here it is:

[Java's Simple Date Format supports only second precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172432/convert-string-with-nanosecond-into-timestamp-in-spark/46173348#46173348)

However, you can still parse the strings to a timestamp in this way:

```
df.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(F.lit("2019-11-19T17:19:39.214841000000"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).select("date").show(5)
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
+-------------------+
```

You can write a custom function like the way mentioned in the above link, which lets you do the ordering using the microseconds in the timestamp.

Please refer : [pault's answer on Convert date string to timestamp in pySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55523281/8805315)

**EDIT**:
I tried with `spark.sql(query)` as well:

```
df = df.withColumn("date_string", F.lit("2019-11-19T17:19:39.214841000000"))
df.registerTempTable("df")

query = """SELECT to_timestamp(date_string, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") as time from df limit 3"""

spark.sql(query).show()
+-------------------+
|               time|
+-------------------+
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
|2019-11-19 17:19:39|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" inside spark.sql("""select ....""") makes it all red on yyyy-MM-dd, etc

Comment: Ok. It was because I was not using paragraph """ in my query. I changed to """ and atleast my 2019-11-19T17:19:39.214841000000 is OK. But still 2019-11-19 dates are coming as NULL>

Comment: For that you can use `"""SELECT to_timestamp(B.SE_TS, "yyyy-MM-dd")"""`

Comment: That will not keep both the formats same. to_date(col,"yyyy-MM-dd") will make it yyyy-MM-dd but I want that also to be 2019-11-19 00:00:00.000000

Comment: One more issue with the first one. It ignores the milliseconds.

Comment: None of it is going to give you microseconds precision, right. Your best bet is to take it to the `timestamp` level and maybe then use the link

Comment: @earl Please read the answer again. **Java's Simple Date Format supports only second precision**

Comment: Yeah. Got it. Both are formatted as expected now. Thanks